# VB.NET Circular Dependency / Duplex Communication between Projects

Tags: vb.net, code-organization, circular-dependency

I have 2 projects

1. UI
2. Functionality

UI references Functionality to call specific functions. Functionality needs to call certain functions that operate UI. This is what I mean by Duplex communication. Is there any way to do this without causing circular dependency?

Should there be 1 main project which simply does all the calling acting as a "wrapper" between UI and Functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "functionality" (business layer) piece probably shouldn't be calling the "ui" puiece. In fact it should need to know anything about it since that is the point of separating your project into layers to begin with.   If you had to change your UI layer to something different, web based, windows form, mobile, etc this should always be independent.

Comment: For the purposes of this project it was mostly for code-organization but I see your point. I left a comment for driis' answer above which gives an example of why I need this to be duplex. How would one go about setting an additional layer as a proxy?

Comment: You could create a proxy that is loosely coupled between the UI and functionality piece and still kee the functionality independent and "unaware" of the type of UI.  (For example the engine of a car shouldn't have to know what the dashboard inside looks like)

Comment: The proxy could handle calls between both if you absolutely have to go this route.

Comment: I get the concept and the analogy is perfect but I don't understand how to apply this proxy. If I put a layer that's referenced in Functionality and references UI it's the same thing and it's still classified as circular dependency.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of the types of calls your functionality layer has to make to the UI?

Comment: Basically I have a function in the UI layer which would change a progress bar and a label in a status strip on each step of a BIGGER Login function in the business layer. But what I'm going to do is split that Login functions into more components that way I can call them from within the UI along with the Progress update function. I guess it should be good even for debugging...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4313/discussion-between-jdross-and-theveloper)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want UI to call Functionality, not the other way around. That's best practice. You can use an event mechanism or callbacks if you need to observe the Functionality project and respond to events.

UI calling Functionality and Functionality calling UI is inadvertently going to be a circular reference. You want to avoid that.

Comment: OK, say I have a progressbar in the UI and a Login function in Functionality... which only returns upon completion. How can I update the progress bar at every step of the Login function's actions?